# Значение слова "кавардак"

Tags: этимология

Смысл слова "кавардак".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сейчас точно не вспомню, где, кажется, в Казахстане, мы ели блюдо под названием "кауардак" - смесь мелко рубленных потрохов, лука и трав. Слово "винегрет" часто обозначает мешанину и неразбериху. По-моему, здесь тот же вариант.

Comment: Не в Узбекистане?
https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA&newwindow=1&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=wS6HVLLxCcHOygPK-YK4Aw&ved=0CCcQsAQ&biw=1213&bih=917  
  
Это, скорее, уйгурское блюдо. А уйгуры - в общем-то и есть узбеки, только китайские.

Comment: Очень может быть. Ездили много, теперь в голове кавардак)) А в Google зайти поленилась. Извините за свинство

Comment: Да господь с вами. В чем свинство-то? Я и не сразу сообразил, за что извиняться-то тут... Просто мне тоже случалось и поездить, и в Москве его поесть ))) Я вам картинки показал,

Все нормально. Я вам даже лайк поставлю, чтоб вы не переживали. )))

Кстати, с точки зрения языка казахский "кавардак" был бы как раз логичнее. Слово, вроде, квалифицируют как кыпчакское, а узбеки относятся к другой группе.

Answer (score 1):

Беспорядок, хаос. Преимущественно - применительно к беспорядку в комнате, личных вещах.

Или вас этимология интересует? Считается, что от казахского или киргизского слова с таким же значением.

Answer (score 1):

Большой толковый словарь дает значение этого слова: беспорядок, неразбериха. В комнате был кавардак

Comment: В комнате был кавардак (не путать с "бардак", то же, что "бордель")